# Icons jiggle while element is expanding

Tags: html, css

I have created a header that becomes sticky, and when it does - it transitions from its fixed width to full width from the center.

For some reason, the icons jiggle in a weird fashion as the transition occurs.

What's even weirder is that they only jiggle at certain widths, so if you can't see what I'm talking about - try varying the width of the window.

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="bg"></div>

  <div id="waypoint"></div>

  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="img-wrapper">
                <img  src="https://www.saunderslandscaping.ca/images/icons/droplet.svg" alt="">
              </span> 
              <span>txt</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          // ... more items
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav.sticky .wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: auto;
  background: #d0d0d0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Here's a **fiddle** demoing the problem (try to change the width)](https://jsfiddle.net/1htqqfvb/4/).

How do I stop the shaking?

Comment: The jiggle is due to odd pixel sizes. For example, if your browser was 5px wide, and you wanted to center something that's 2px, it's not possible. It will be off either to the left or right by 1px. That is a simplified version of what's happening to you.

Comment: @kthornbloom Yeah, and when the transition occurs the icons move from left to right until it's completed. Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Partial Solution

I managed to figure out the source of the problem and partially fix it. What I'v come up with is not perfect, but it pretty much gets the job done.

---

**The problem** is when the width of the screen is an odd number. In that case, as the transition occurs, the icons move one pixel to each side because they can't be centered with half a pixel.

This happens more frequently on Windows because on Windows the scrollbar takes up an odd width off the width of the screen. For example, my resolution is 1920px wide, and the scrollbar takes up 17px, so that leaves the window width at 1903px.

---

To fix it, I added a script that checks if the window width is odd. If so, it shortens the `transition-wrapper` by one pixel (in this case, the `transition-wrapper` is the `wrapper`).

Here it is:

```
if ($window.width() % 2 != 0)
  $transitionWrapper.css('right', '1px');
```

**The only problem now is** after the transition takes place, the wrapper needs to return to it's full width, so there is a one pixel jump of the whole thing.

That's OK I guess, but if anyone has a better solution without that jump, I would love to hear it. I'm still not approving this answer because it's imperfect.

---

**Update:**

Changing the added `right` value to `-1px` instead of `1px` actually solves the jiggling completely. I don't really have a good explanation, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `transition` from `all` to just `background-color` and `width`, the jiggling stops. Try adding the transition to only the elements that change during the transition.

```
transition: 1s background-color ease, 1s width ease;
```

Also, add this to the `.img-wrapper`

```
.img-wrapper {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

See my updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt5zLtn8/) to see it work.

Comment: OP want also the animation from the width, look his JSFiddle.

Comment: @Garric15 Thanks for the heads up, updated my Fiddle.

Comment: @Roy Thanks for the quick answer. However, your suggestions did not fix the problem. If you change the width a couple of times you'll notice the icons still jiggle. Cancelling the transition on the `width` does solve the problem, but I have to have the width expanding.

Comment: @Gofilord Have you checked my JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried changing the width, in your fiddle? It may be worth mentioning that I am noticing that this problem is more frequent on Windows and less frequent on Macs.

Comment: @Gofilord What browser are you using? Because no problem in Chrome, Firefox or Edge (latest versions).

Comment: I have tried Chrome on Windows 10 and Chrome on OSX El Capitan. On both, I get unexpected behavior of jiggling only on some widths. You may need to change the width a couple of times until you see it.

Comment: @Gofilord I changed it multiple times on Chrome's latest version on Windows/Mac and (still) no unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Roy Thanks for all the help. I pretty much figured it out though. You can look at my answer below.